# XML Schema: how to declare complexType that has either attribute or child with the same name

Tags: xml, xsd

With my XSD schema I want the element to have a required additional value that can be specified either in element's attribute or in its child.

Example: The following elements should be allowed:

```
<flower color="red" />
```

or:

```
<flower><color>red</color></flower>
```

But the following elements should not be valid:

```
<flower />
```

and:

```
<flower></flower>
```

and:

```
<flower color="red"><color>blue</color></flower>
```

And I have absolutely no idea how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming XSD 1.0, the sample below is a starting point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:simpleType name="flowerColor">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="flowerVariantA">
        <xsd:attribute name="color" type="flowerColor" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="flowerVariantB">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="color" type="flowerColor"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="flower" type="flowerVariantA"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

VariantA and B are mutually exclusive and match one or the other of your sample XML. If your intent was to allow both at the same time, then XSD 1.0 doesn't allow a "choice" of content which mixes attributes with elements.

Also, you cannot control self-closing of XML elements; this means that with VariantA, the following is valid:

```
<flower color="red"></flower>
```

Answer (score 3):

In XSD 1.0, your only option is to document the constraint in prose.  (As is done, for example, in the schema for schemas, which has a similar constraint on element declarations.)

In XSD 1.1, you can use an assertion to document and enforce the constraint.  Modfying the schema document suggested by Petru Gardea a bit, we have:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/colors" 
       xmlns:tns="http://example.com/colors" 
       elementFormDefault="qualified" 
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="flowerColor">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:normalizedString">
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="flowerVariantC">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="color" 
                  type="tns:flowerColor" 
                  minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>  
    <xs:attribute name="color" 
                  type="tns:flowerColor" 
                  use="optional"/>
    <xs:assert test="(./tns:color or ./@color)
        and not(./tns:color and ./@color)"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="flower" type="tns:flowerVariantC"/>    
  <xs:element name="test"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Given the schema document just shown and the following instance, Saxon rejects the first and fourth flower elements as invalid.

```
<test xmlns="http://example.com/colors"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/colors colors.xsd">
  <flower/>
  <flower color="red"/>
  <flower><color>blue</color></flower>
  <flower color="blue"><color>blue</color></flower>
</test>
```

(That said, my instinct is to advise against this design as unnecessarily complex:  choose to make color an attribute, or choose to make it a child.  The fact that each is a plausible design does *not* mean that allowing it to vary within the document is a plausible design.)